# To display values of variables being used

Tags: matlab

Consider the example,

```
    x=rand(5,1)
    y=rand(5,1)
    X=x.^2+y.^2
    d=min(X)
```

I want to pick THOSE values of x and y corresponding to which value of 'd' is being stored!
How do i do that?

Comment: explain a little more what you mean, possibly an example?

Comment: LET ME SAY x=2, y=3 then X= 13, when x=3, y= 4, X= 25, x=4, y=5 then X= 41. As d= min(X) => d= min(13,25,41) = 13. Now 13 is corresponding to x=2 and y=3. i want to display this x and y. How do i do that?

Comment: @Misha I know what exponents are. You did not explain whether you want to try all combinations of `x` and `y`, or just the individual like indices being multiplied together

Comment: @MZimmerman6 on individual indices not all the combinations

Comment: @Misha in that case, did you even try anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking to find the x and y values for the minimum that you found using `d=min(X)` I think you want to use:

```
x(X==d)
y(X==d)
```

Comment: No problem, I've been there. Happy Matlabbing!

Answer (score 0):

After thinking about it, I think this is what you mean. You want the values of `x` and `y` that will have created the minimum value that is returned by `min(X)`. The code below will do this

```
x=rand(5,1);
y=rand(5,1);
[xx,yy] = meshgrid(x,y);
X=xx.^2+yy.^2;
[i,j] = find(X == min(X(:)));
minX = x(i)
minY = y(j)
```

Or there is a cleaner version using `bsxfun` that removes the use of `meshgrid`

```
x=rand(5,1);
y=rand(5,1)';
multFunc = @(x,y) x.^2+y.^2;
X = bsxfun(multFunc,x,y);
[i,j] = find(X == min(X(:)));
minX = x(i)
minY = y(j)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x=rand(5,1);
y=rand(5,1);
X=[x.^2+y.^2 x y ]; %Put all together
d=find(X(:,1)'==min(X(:,1))); %Get row of minimum

X(d,2:end) %gives you x & y
```